# Probability-using expectation value

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

A coin which has probability 0.75 of coming up heads is tossed three times.
Let X be the number of heads observed.
Find E(X^2), give your answer to 2 decimal places.

Comment: There are only $4$ possible values for $X$.  Just compute the probability of each and use the standard method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess -

You’d do
$$
=1^2 \cdot 0.75^1 + 2^2 \cdot 0.75^2 + 3^2 \cdot 0.75^3
$$
Which would give you an expected value, but this seems a little simple

My only concern is that it doesn’t take into consideration say, if I rolled a head once, this could happen three times, ie htt or tth or tht - would this take any significance in the answer of this question.

Comment: +1 Welcome to Math.SE! This is correct. I would include a guess in the question itself, though, instead of writing up the stand-alone answer. Hope you stay around and contribute to this site.

Comment: My only concern is that it doesn’t take into consideration say, if I rolled a head once, this could happen three times, ie htt or tth or tht - would this take any significance in the answer of this question.

Comment: The probabilities are wrong. For example:  there are $3$ ways to get a single Head, as you point out, so the probability of $X=1$ is $3\times .75\times .25^2$.  And so on.

Comment: Would we also consider when x=0? Ie there’s no heads

Comment: If $p_k$ is probability to get $k$ heads, you get $0p_0 = 0$ as the first term, so it does not matter.